# Replace numbers with letters in a part of string, in comma separated list in Perl

Tags: string, perl

If I have a file of comma separated length 10 number strings (`0001010101` for example) and want to reformat the string to replace the last two characters of each string with a letter where `01` is `A`, and so on up to `26` being `Z` what is the beat way to do this in Perl?

Sample file content:

```
0109150103,1807111225,0305102306
```

Output would then be:

```
01091501C,18071112Y,03051023F
```

Assume I would do a split on the string into an array and then evaluate each to look at last 2 digits with a substr and replace with appropriate letter. Wondering what the most efficient way to do this vice looking to see if `01` and then setting to `A`, and so on.

The brute force way I would do is like:

```
$data=<file.txt>;
@tokens=split /,/,$data;
while(@tokens)
{
 print substr($_,0,7)."A," if(substr($_,8,2)=='01');
 print substr($_,0,7)."B," if(substr($_,8,2)=='02');
#.
#.
 print substr($_,0,7)."Z," if(substr($_,8,2)=='26');
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you tried, and what results you obtained, compared to what you would like to obtain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can use [chr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html)

```
echo "0109150103,1807111225,0305102306" | 
    perl -wnE'@t = split /,/; s/(..)$/chr(64+$1)/e for @t; say for @t'
```

where `/e` modifier makes the replacement part in regex be evaluated as code.

Comment: @zdim.. great answer!

Comment: ``echo "0109150103,1807111225,0305102306" | perl -pE 's/(\d\d)(?!\d)/chr(64+$1)/ge'``

Comment: @Miller Nice, and very efficient :)  I thought they'd need the array anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl!

```
$ echo "0109150103,1807111225,0305102306" | perl -ne ' while(/(.+?)(..)(,|$)/g) { print "$1",chr(64+$2),"\n" } '
01091501C
18071112Y
03051023F
$
```

adding Miller's solution

```
echo "0109150103,1807111225,0305102306" | perl -pE 's/(\d\d)(?!\d)/chr(64+$1)/ge'
```

Comment: A nice way to process in place, without splitting into a list (some data copying does happen).  Also see @Miller's comment under my post for similar but which doesn't restart regex engine in a loop (which is an overhead with regex)

Comment: @zdim.. need your help on qstn 54105509 - I'm not able to combine backreference and lookahead.. can you give a try

Comment: OK, that's a good idea and a good answer ... what other do you want to do? To "match" somehow if backreference is not there (with negative lookahead)?